# Node.js streams - property '_eventsCount' has already been set

Tags: node.js

I am trying to reuse same writable stream to manually pipe to /dev/null

I have this:

```
const writable = fs.createWriteStream('/dev/null');

k1.stdout.pipe(writable);
k1.stderr.pipe(writable);

setTimeout(function(){
   k2.stdout.pipe(writable);
   k2.stderr.pipe(writable);
},100);
```

and I am getting this error:

```
 property '_eventsCount' has already been set
```

I tried this too:

```
const writable = fs.createWriteStream('/dev/null', {end: false});
```

and that didn't change the error.

any ideas?